# Angular MatTable - center expandable row inside viewport

Tags: angular

Being that I'm using a `MatTable` with expandable rows, it would be handy to auto-scroll to the vertical center of the viewport when expanding.
Does Angular offer some helper function to accomplish this or do I have to code my own?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scroll to the center or a particular row in the mat-table, you could pass in the row (in this case it would fire on a click event):

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8" #proctable>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Process Sequence No. Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="sequence">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Seq. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let process">
            {{process.sequence}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Process Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let process">
            {{process.name}}</span>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr (click)="scrollToRow(row)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" mat-row></tr>
</table>
```

And then call the following in your handler method:

```
scrollToRow(row) {
  row.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to be sure it is scrolled at the center? Or this does it already?

Comment: It should scroll to the center.  Please mark this as correct if the solution worked for you.